# Replace Column Names in R

Tags: r

How to replace the column names in r, for example say columns A,B,C,D, I wish to change all as A_id, B_id, C_id, D_id, so all column names will have "_id" at the end.

Using str_replace_all we can find the specific string and replace, but I don't know how to change at the end

```
df %>% str_replace_all( '_', '_id')
```

Expecting in a single sort of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `names` or `colnames` function like this:

```
names(df) <- paste0(names(df), "_id")
```

Or you can combine this with `gsub` to only replace specific things, e.g if you want to replace any names in the `iris` dataset to use space not full stop you can write:

```
df <- head(iris)
names(df) <- gsub("[.]", " ", names(df))
```

Comment: no problem. feel free to accept as answer to help future users

Comment: there should be a tick mark below the up and downvote buttons in the top left corner of my answer. clicking the tick means accepting this as the answer